# Convert ANSI encoding to another encoding through the Linux shell

Tags: linux, shell, csv, encoding

How can I code from the Linux shell? I have a package of CSV files in ANSI and I want to convert to an encoding that doesn't have accents: ã, ç, á, í ...

How can I do it without involving any programming language?

Comment: What does this have to do with ANSI? It sounds like you're talking about UTF-8.

Comment: Why are you asking not to use a program on a programming site?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using the GNU version of `iconv(1)` (Since you have this tagged linux it seems a safe bet):

```sh
iconv -f MS-ANSI -t US-ASCII//TRANSLIT input.csv > output.csv
```

(I'm guessing on the `MS-ANSI` from encoding; `iconv --list | grep -Fi ANSI` shows several other possibilities. Or your source character set could be something completely different.)